# Change Font Family Based On Other CSS Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the font-family of a class (.button) based on the font-family value of h6. I realize this can't be done with CSS, but couldn't find a solution directly through JS. I wish it were as easy applying the styles in a stylesheet, but the h6 value is gerenated dynamically by the user. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It can be achieved with both CSS and JS. Could you update with a runnable [mcve]?

Comment: You need to define a fallback font for cases like this. The issue is not clear, please elaborate on the problem that you're having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way to do it, since you're using jQuery.

Just for demonstration, you can see that the button takes the font of the H6 element after you click the button.

If you want this to happen immediately, remove the `click()` function by deleting the first and last line of the JS code (first code block).

```js
$('.my-button').click( function(){
  var font = $('.my-title').css("font-family");
  var weight = $('.my-title').css("font-weight");
  $('.my-button').css('font-family', font);
  $('.my-button').css('font-weight', weight);
});
```

```css
.my-title {
  font-family: "Lucida Handwriting";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.my-button {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h6 class="my-title">Hello World</h6>

<button class="my-button">Some Button</button>
```

Comment: But, this doesn't do what the OP stated they need to do.

Comment: This code takes the font-family of a h6 element and applies it to a button, which is what I *think* the OP wants to do. If he wants the button to have a font different from the h6, then your answer will work for him. In any case, I believe this would help someone else, if not the OP.

Comment: Your code assumes that the button's font should be the same as the `h6` and it assumes that this should happen on a button click. I don't get either of those things from the question.

Comment: Did you read this answer at all? The button click is for demonstration only. And like I said, this is what I **_THINK_** (perhaps if I write it in all caps, you would see it) the OP wants. I could be wrong. You could be right. No one is forcing anyone to use an answer. The OP will take what he needs and ignore the others. If this doesn't help the OP, it would help someone else in future.

Comment: This was pretty much what I was trying to do! I adjusted the function a bit and got stuck trying to add "font-style" and "font-weight". `$(document).ready(function () { var font = $('h6').css("font-family"); var style = $('h6').css("font-style"); var weight = $('h6').css("font-weight"); $('.wp-block-button__link').css('cssText','font-family:'+ font); // $('.wp-block-button__link').css('cssText','font-style:'+ style); // $('.wp-block-button__link').css('cssText','font-weight:'+ weight); });`

Comment: Hi @TroyRiemer, I think your last commented line took out the closing bit of the `ready()` function. I tried it in this codepen and it works. [https://codepen.io/stanyy/pen/NEzjrE](https://codepen.io/stanyy/pen/NEzjrE). I'll be happy to tweak it further if you want. You can accept this answer if it worked for you. Cheers.

Comment: UPDATE: I have updated the code in the pen to work without `cssText`, which actually replaces previous styles on the element. I'll update this answer to include multiple css attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Have the potential `font-family` styles pre-set up in classes ahead of time and then use `if/then` logic to set the correct class on the element. The cornerstone of this is the [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property and its `.add()` method.

```js
// Get references to the elements we need to work with
let h6 = document.querySelector("h6");
let btn = document.querySelector("button.button");

// Use if/then/else logic to set the button class
if(h6.classList.contains("foo")){
  btn.classList.add("newFoo");
} else if(h6.classList.contains("bar")){
  btn.classList.add("newBar");  
} else if(h6.classList.contains("baz")) {
  btn.classList.add("newBaz");  
}
```

```css
/* Example of what the pre-existing classes might be: */
.foo { font-family:"Comic Sans MS"; font-size:2em; margin:.5em; }

/* New styles that will be used to override: */
.newFoo { font-family:"Times New Roman"; }
.newBar { font-family:sans-serif; }
.newBaz { font-family:monospace; }
```

```html
<h6 class="foo">foo</h6>
<button class="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear enough for me, but I tried to answer you with a more general solution for your problem!

In the demo below, I've created an `input` as if the user will type a value there, and a button with `button` id, and its `font-size` will be changed according to the value provided from the user within the `input` field

```js
var sizeInput = document.querySelector("#sizeInput")
var myBtn = document.querySelector("#button")
var sizeFromTheUser

sizeInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // Update the variable's value based on the changed value from the user
  sizeFromTheUser = sizeInput.value
  // Change the font-size based on the given value
  switch(sizeFromTheUser) {
    case "h1":
      myBtn.style.fontSize = "2em"
    break;
    case "h2":
      myBtn.style.fontSize = "1.5em"
    break;
    case "h3":
      myBtn.style.fontSize = "1.17em"
    break;
    case "h4":
      myBtn.style.fontSize = "1em"
    break;
    case "h5":
      myBtn.style.fontSize = "0.83em"
    break;
    case "h6":
      myBtn.style.fontSize = "0.75em"
    break;
  }
  
})
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="sizeInput" />
  <button id="button">This is text!</button>
```

You can apply the same to the `font-family` property with different `Switch` cases that meets your needs, or even using a different logic, but I just gave you a generic example that might be helpful in your situation!

Comment: Why not show your answer using `font-family` instead of `font-size` since the question was about `font-family`?

Comment: His question is very unclear for me, I didn't actually know what he precisely means. Especially when he mentioned the `h6`, I was wondering; Did he mean `<h6>`, Hmmm... not really, maybe he meant the `font-size` instead of the `font-family` and he wanted the `<h6>` size? LOL, I made too many assumptions before answering this @ScottMarcus! :D